# Run script from Ubuntu terminal after stripe event

Tags: ubuntu, stripe-payments

I have a Linux (Ubuntu) server and I would like to run a script from my Ubuntu terminal after each new Stripe subscription. To do this, my server would have to be permanently connected to my stripe account.

I could do this with a crontab that runs, every 15 minutes, a script  that connects to the stripe API and detects when a new event occurs. The script would compare the active subscribers with those listed in a file saved on my server in the previous 15 minutes.

I am wondering if using Stripe CLI you could also run a script from the linux command line every time there is a change in subscriptions (new subscription or unsubscribe). In this case, Stripe CLI should permanently connect my linux server to my Stripe account and should allow running a script based on the following condition:

"If there is a new subscription or cancellation in my Stripe account, then run script"

I would like to know if this alternative is possible and if this would be a better option than the first one. I would also like to know how to perform this alternative.

My question is how to enter the condition from the result of the following command line:

```
$ stripe listen --events=customer.subscription.created
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This option would force the server to be working continuously. I would like to know if there is a better option.

A better option for what? To hibernate the server? To prevent a selfmade script from running to detect new events? What about [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)?

### Go with Bash

This one-liner starts Stripe CLI to listen `customer.subscription.created` events and continously parses its output with `jq` (the set of extracted data is for demo purposes):

```
stripe listen \
  --events=customer.subscription.created \
  --format JSON | 
    while IFS='' read event; do \
      echo $event | grep 'data' | \
      jq '{event: .type, \
           subscr_created: .data.object.created | todate, \
           customer: .data.object.customer, \
           amount: .data.object.plan.amount}'; \
    done
```

Example output:

```
{
  "event": "customer.subscription.created",
  "subscr_created": "2022-06-16T10:12:24Z",
  "customer": "cus_Fr31GH4ac3SFhk",
  "amount": 2000
}
```

Comment: Seeker, I have edited the question. I think it's more accurate now

Comment: It looks like you don't intend to use [tried and tested web application options](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/quickstart) and you're restricting yourself to bash programming. Therefore, if you choose between your two options, then, in terms of real-time updates, the second option is the best. Just redirect output of `stripe listen` command to your script. If your script needs more detailed output, use `--format JSON` flag.

Comment: I guess I would have to use a bash script to put "stripe listen" in a while infinite loop to continuously compare the output with a file saved at the previous instant that stored the output of stripe listen. Then I would run the bash script with "nohup script.sh &". Would this be the proper procedure?

Comment: I would not put the `stripe listen` command in an infinite while loop, but read its output inside the loop. See update in the answer.